# how to update a component from another child component in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

Right. I've been googling for days and can't seem to find an example that works and that I understand.

I've currently got three components, ButtonComponent, SecondButton, and TextComponent.

I already have it such that tapping Button can update State and thus change the text in TextComponent (if i set setState to the text string on line 39).

How can I change it so that it will change to a string of text that I can set from the button itself rather than the function fired by the button, so that SecondButton can fire the same function as Button, but update the text to something different.

I figure it must be a small tweak to onPress? but everything I try keeps complaining about objects and things being undefined.

Thanks.

```
import { setStatusBarNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible, StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';


function ButtonComponent({changeText}) {
  console.log(`2. ${changeText} from inside Button Component`)
  return(
    <Button title="change text" onPress={changeText} />
  )

}

function SecondButton({changeText}){
  return(
  <Button title="change text again" onPress={changeText} />
  )
}

function TextComponent({text}) {
  console.log(`3. ${text} from inside Text Component`) //
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default function App() {
console.log('1 .start')

const [text, setText] = useState('default text'); // declared in the screen

const changeText = ({newtext}) => {
    setText(newtext)
    console.log(`4. ${text} just after changeText`)
  }

  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <ButtonComponent changeText={changeText}/>
     <SecondButton changeText={changeText}/>
      <TextComponent text={text}/>
    </View>
  )
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'red',
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to answer your question, but I see a few issues before we can address it. 1) You shouldn't use Button, the current best option in react-native is Pressable. 2) When you use the function changeText in ButtonComponent and SecondButton you are not really providing any string so that shouldn't work or maybe it will just show an empty string or undefined. Please can you review that?

Comment: About the question itself if you want to change the text to a different string then function changeText needs to receive a different a different string.

Comment: How do I make changeText recieve the new string from the Button (or Pressable if I change it)?

Comment: onPress= () => changeText ("some string")
or in this case:
onPress= () => changeText ( { newtext: "some string" } )

Comment: I get error: Can't find variable: changeText

Comment: I added it as an answer so you can see the code

Comment: thanks. don't know why it didn't work when i copied it before.

Comment: no worries, let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SecondButton({changeText}){
  return(
  <Button 
    title="change text again" 
    onPress={() => changeText( { newtext: "different string" })}
  />
  )
}
```